# open other view with segue only works by pressing button

Tags: swift, segue

I want to open an other view controller, after checking if it is the first run of the app.
It works when I press a button but not when I call the method openMap

```
class TutorialController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //check if the app opens for the first time
    if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce"))
    {
        // app already launched
        print("not first launch")
        openMap()
    }
    else
    {
        // This is the first launch ever
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        print("first launch")
        openTutorial()
    }
}
func openTutorial(){

}
@IBAction func openMap(){
    print("openmap opened")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "openMap", sender: nil)

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you've connected your button to `@IBAction func openMap()`
if so, you should not call `openMap()` action inside your `viewDidLoad`, but use the same code `performSegue(withIdentifier: "openMap", sender: nil)` instead in your `viewDidAppear`:

```
if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce"))
    {
        // app already launched
        print("not first launch")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "openMap", sender: nil)
    }
...
```

If it doesn't work, you've probably made a mistake with creation of your segue and have connected Button to the destination ViewController directly in your storyboard instead of connecting two controllers:[image: segue between controllers]

If so, just remove the old segue, and re-crete it in the way as it is on the image above and assign the same segue id "openMap"

EDITED:
Please, move performing of your segue to the viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad, because viewDidLoad is called when the ViewController object is created and it's not yet attached to the window.

Comment: I tried to copy the code in the viewDid load method before, it doesn't worked. And I connect both Controllers not the button.

Comment: Please, try to move it in viewDidAppear. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I understand is that you want to perform a segue "openMap" when it HasLaunchedOnce. Well what you're doing wrong is that you're calling an @IBAction func. This is my suggestion

if you still want to have that button

1. create a function and name if whatever you want. Inside this function perform this segue. Link this function to the if else statement and the button.

eg:

```
//if else statement
if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce"))
{
        // app already launched
        print("not first launch")
        anotherFunction()
}

//@ibaction (scrap this if you don't want the button)
@IBAction func openMap()
{
    print("openmap opened")
    anotherFunction()

}

//another function
func anotherFunction()
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "openMap", sender: nil)
}
```

hope this helps